# #NAME errors when book is opened, works fine after that

Tags: excel, vba

We have an Excel book that has many custom functions in VBA. One of the other sheets, "CF", uses our `BALLANCE` VBA function to pick-n-place some data to produce a ledger. Other sheets then refer to cells within "CF" to make running totals and such.

When you first open the book, some of those total cells will have `#NAME` in them. The cells on "CF" the are referring to do *not* have `#NAME`. And if you do a F2 when you're in one, it calculates fine. And it continues to work fine after that.

It looks like a timing issue of some sort, but I can't imagine what. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it the cells containing the UDF that show #Name on first opening? This is because they recalculate on open (and various other events). And do you have macro security settings that don't allow for automatic running of macros?

Comment: @QHarr - no, the UDF cells are fine, that's what's weird.

Comment: Do you require the sheet to recalcualte on open? Otherwise just set the calculation mode to manual, then the problem should be fixed as well.

Comment: @Luuklag - yes, the sheet has to recalc on open

Comment: Dare I say it: Ditch the UDFS in favour of Excel formulas wherever possible, so that Excel's calculation engine works faster, better, and more smoothly.  What kinds of things do these UDFS do? Do they do anything that can't be achieved with clever use of Formulas and PivotTables?